# Maven Dependency Plugin Copy Goal should ignore missing dependencies of ArtifactItem

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I have the following POM snippet:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>${g}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${a}</artifactId>
                    <version>${v}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <destFileName>webapplication.war</destFileName>
                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This fails, if the given artifact does not have its parent and its dependencies in the repository. Can I somehow instruct maven to ignore the missing dependencies? I just want to copy this single artifact anyway.

Comment: why are you trying to copy a war file? For what purpose?

Comment: I have to upload it to a tomcat instance.

Comment: Bad idea. Usually you build your artifacts and deploy them to a repository manager and start the deployment on the appropriate environments from there via CI solution like Jenkins etc. So there is never a need to do some fancy copying of war files...Apart from that this will only work on a particular machine...

Comment: @khmarbaise the code snippet above runs in a CI solution (Jenkins) in a pipeline script. The tomcat maven plugin works so, that it needs a war file to upload. So I have to fetch the maven artifakt from maven repository so that I can upload it to tomcat. I don't understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: So you do the build and the deployment to an environment in one go?

Comment: No. There is a release build job, which builds the project into a war file. This war file is stored in maven repository. There is a second job for deployment, this should download the war with the specific version to a temp folder (target folder) and upload it to the tomcat instance.